# Python, non-blocking threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous

There are a lot of tutorials etc. on Python and asynchronous coding techniques, but I am having difficulty filtering the through results to find what I need. I am new to Python, so that doesn't help.

#### Setup

I currently have two objects that look sort of like this (please excuse my python formatting):

```
class Alphabet(parent):
    def init(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def style_alphabet(callback):
        # this method presumably takes a very long time, and fills out some properties
        # of the Alphabet object
        callback()


class myobj(another_parent):
    def init(self):
        self.alphabets = []
        refresh()
        
    def foo(self):
        for item in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            letters = new Alphabet(item)
            self.alphabets.append(letters)
        self.screen_refresh()

        for item in self.alphabets
            # this is the code that I want to run asynchronously. Typically, my efforts
            # all involve passing item.style_alphabet to the async object / method
            # and either calling start() here or in Alphabet
            item.style_alphabet(self.screen_refresh)
            
    def refresh(self):
        foo()
        # redraw screen, using the refreshed alphabets
        redraw_screen()

    def screen_refresh(self):
        # a lighter version of refresh()
        redraw_screen()
```

The idea is that the main thread initially draws the screen with incomplete `Alphabet` objects, fills out the Alphabet objects, updating the screen as they complete.

I've tried a number of implementations of threading.Tread, Queue.Queue, and even futures, and for some reason they either haven't worked, or they have blocked the main thread. so that the initial draw doesn't take place.

#### A few of the async methods I've attempted:

```
class Async (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, f, cb):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.f  = f
        self.cb = cb

    def run(self):
        self.f()
        self.cb()
```

---

```
def run_as_thread(f):
    # When I tried this method, I assigned the callback to a property of "Alphabet"
    thr = threading.Thread(target=f)
    thr.start()
```

---

```
def run_async(f, cb):
    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    result = pool.apply_async(func=f, args=args, callback=cb)
```

Comment: Could you show us how you're instantiating your `Async` class and calling its `start()` method (and similarly for `run_as_thread()`)?

Comment: Also, calling `letters.style_alphabet()` in the last block in `myobj.foo()` is probably not what you want (it should be `item.style_alphabet()`, no?).  But I'm guessing that was a cut and past error of some kind, as this is obviously not the actual code you're trying to run.

Comment: Twisted framwork offers you whay you are looking for...if you want me to tell specifically.. checkout threads.deferToThread() . it does what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks for noticing the letters/item error, Alp - it's fixed

Comment: Alp - the Async class and run_as_thread() method are complete as written - is that my problem? I've never done this type of thing before.

Comment: deeshank - I was hoping to avoid using code that wasn't part of python's core, because I'd like to keep the code portable. That said, I am more interested in getting this to work, so I'll see if I can't get Twisted to work. Can you offer a code example so I don't miss something important?

Comment: Alp - I think I misunderstood your question about `start()`. `run_as_thread()` calls the `start()` method; my use of the Async class involved creating the object and then simply calling `start() on it.

Comment: here's a [code example that shows how a GUI object is populated with filenames that are generated in a background thread without blocking the GUI](http://askubuntu.com/a/183315/3712)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a thread pool to deal with this use pattern.  Try creating a queue and handing a reference off to all the worker threads. Add task objects to the queue from the main thread.  Worker threads pull objects from the queue and invoke the functions.  Add an event to each task to be signaled on the worker thread at task completion.  Keep a list of task objects on the main thread and use polling to see if the UI needs an update.  One can get fancy and add a pointer to a callback function on the task objects if needed.

My solution was inspired by what I found on Google: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187-python-thread-pool/

I kept improving on that design to add features and give the threading, multiprocessing, and parallel python modules a consistent interface.  My implementation is at:

https://github.com/nornir/nornir-pools

Docs:

http://nornir.github.io/packages/nornir_pools.html

If you are new to Python and not familiar with the GIL I suggest doing a search for Python threading and the global interpreter lock (GIL).  It isn’t a happy story.  Generally I find I need to use the multiprocessing module to get decent performance.

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: Thanks for lead, Xycor, and welcome to SO! Your answer is on my list of things to try, but the link you posted to the git repo is broken. Can you fix it?

Comment: When you said "multithreading", did you mean [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), which bypasses the GIL issue by using subprocesses instead of threads?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with python to say. My goal is to run some code that doesn't interfere with the main thread, then call a method on the main thread that updates the screen. I'm trying to create a "responsive gui"

Comment: Fixed the link and name of the module.